# Mappoint 2009 Europe MapPointControl.ocx

Tags: vb6, ocx, mappoint

I have an old legacy VB6 app that I support, which uses the MapPointControl.ocx.  Customers are saying it doesnt work with Mappoint 2009.

Having Googled, it would appear the European addition of Mappoint shipped with a bad OCX file on it.  Apparently this has now been sorted on the latest CDs, but that doesnt help my customers who are still moaning.

Is this true?  Do I just need a replacement .OCX, and if so where from?  Microsofts site is unhelpful.

Comment: Have you tried Microsoft technical support for MapPoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No first hand information, but I "binged" Microsoft and found this post that suggests that using the mappointcontrol.ocx from the North American edition will fix your problem.

http://www.microsoft.com/communities/newsgroups/en-us/default.aspx?dg=microsoft.public.mappoint&tid=632b5959-0a2d-46d6-827b-dfa04ebbc17c&cat=&lang=en&cr=US&sloc=&p=1

Hope this fixes it for you.

Comment: Yes, I also read that too, but I cant find anywhere to download it.

Comment: My bad - I assumed you had it to develop with. It looks like it's been fixed. A phone call to Microsoft support should get you the fix. Can you get one of your customer's information and get the fixed ocx, then distribute that to everyone else?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there was a mess up with the first month or two of shipped MapPoint 2009 Europes, and the OCX file was corrupt. I understand it can be downloaded from the Microsoft website. Or now you can use MapPoint 2010 (or soon, 2011) instead. MapPoint 2010 adds some nice map style additions and, of course, has data additions/improvements.